# Download youtube video in R

Tags: r, youtube

I am trying to write a script in R that will download several youtube movies. This is one of them: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHm8otvMVTs (I come to this youtube page from a course page where the youtube links to all of the videos in this course are provided, so my script will follow that set of links, go to the respective youtube pages, and fetch the mp4's).

Although I have found several discussions on stackoverflow (and elsewhere) on how to retrieve the actual link to the video, I am still totally lost as to how to automatically find it. (also, I keep seeing comments that youtube has recently changed its system, so most of those solutions don't work any longer anyway). 
All I need is to be able to recognize the actual link on the youtube html-page (I am find with regex, so once I know what to look for, I can automate it for multiple youtube movies). So the main question remains: how can I find the actual link to the mp4 for youtube pages like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHm8otvMVTs or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BO6XJSaFYzk
I would appreciate any help on this, thank you.

Comment: Youtube is not easy to download from. You can take a look at [youtube-dl project](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) to see how they do it (or to simply exec from R).

Comment: Thanks, @Amadan ,  I'll study the youtube-dl source code, that is an excellent suggestion.

Comment: @FoggyDay R is what I know, so that is why. But this is really a youtube question, not an R one. The answer to this question would be useful to anyone, regardless of which language they use.